# Retrieve Yahoo email details using C#

Tags: c#, pop3

I am trying to retrieve mails on my Yahoo account using C#. I tested OpenPop to do that I write that

```
Pop3Client objClient = new Pop3Client();
objClient.Connect("pop.mail.yahoo.com", 995, true);
objClient.Authenticate("username","pass",AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
int msgCount = objClient.GetMessageCount();
MessageBox.Show(msgCount.ToString());
```

The problem that the server always did not accept user credentials but I'm sure the credentials are OK.

I tried the same code with my gmail account and every thing goes ok is something missing Yahoo want me to set it?

Comment: _"the server always did not accept user credentials"_ - what's the **exact** error?

Comment: Server did not accept user credentials  --- this is error message that I getting

Comment: @weismat the third argument to [`Connect()`](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.Connect2.html) states he's using SSL.

Comment: @user1369192 does it work in a mail client like Outlook or Thunderbird? Are you supplying the correct User ID? The [manual](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_CLASSIC&locale=en_US&id=SLN3213) states: _"Please note: Your ID is typically your email address without the "@yahoo.com";"_

Comment: I tried , without using  "@yahoo.com " . still it is not working. getting the same error  Also for the above code it is enabled SSL      objClient.Connect( server, port, SSL ( true/ false);

Answer (score 1):

In order to access Yahoo mail via an email program you will need to be a Yahoo Mail Plus subscriber.

```
1. Sign in to Yahoo Mail.
2. Move your cursor over the gear icon (Gear Icon) and select Mail Options.
3. Select POP & Forwarding.
- The "Access your Yahoo Mail elsewhere" option displays.
4. Select the radio button next to Access Yahoo Mail via POP.
5. Click Save.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
try
 {
    if (pop3Client.Connected)
        pop3Client.Disconnect();

    pop3Client.Connect("pop.mail.yahoo.com", 995, true);
    pop3Client.Authenticate("your@yahoo.com", "yourpassword");
    int count = pop3Client.GetMessageCount();
}
catch (InvalidLoginException)
{
   //MessageBox.Show(this, "The server did not accept the user credentials!", "POP3 Server Authentication");
}
catch (PopServerNotFoundException)
{
   //MessageBox.Show(this, "The server could not be found", "POP3 Retrieval");
}
catch (PopServerLockedException)
{
   //MessageBox.Show(this, "The mailbox is locked. It might be in use or under maintenance. Are you connected elsewhere?", "POP3 Account Locked");
}
catch (LoginDelayException)
{
   //MessageBox.Show(this, "Login not allowed. Server enforces delay between logins. Have you connected recently?", "POP3 Account Login Delay");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   //MessageBox.Show(this, "Error occurred retrieving mail. " + e.Message, "POP3 Retrieval");
}
```

Comment: this is waht I was wrote. But I need solution for . If have solution it is more helful. I am in a critical situation